# PDF of the sum of independent normal and uniform random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a continuous uniform random variable $P$ and a standard normal random variable $X$.

The pdf of $P$ is: $\frac{1}{b-a}$

and the pdf for $X$ is: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$

How to find the PDF of $Y=P+X$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions

Comment: You will not find anything more convenient than $$f_{P+X}(x)=\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bf_X(x-u)du$$

Answer (score 8):

Let $P\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ and $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be independent random variables. Their PDFs are

$$\begin{align}g_P(x) &= \frac{1}{b-a},\qquad\quad 0<x<1 \\ \varphi(x) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2},\,\,-\infty<x<\infty\end{align}$$

Then

$$\begin{align}f_{X+P}(x) &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_P(x)\varphi(x-u)du \\ &=\frac{1}{b-a} \int\limits_a^b\varphi(x-u)du \\ &= \frac{1}{2(b-a)} \left[ {\rm erf}\left(\frac{b-x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) - {\rm erf}\left(\frac{a-x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \right] \end{align}$$

with

$${\rm erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$$

being the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). A plot showing the difference between the normal distribution and $f_{X+P}$ looks like this:

[image]